# 90’s/early 00’s tv show about teens or young adults who work at a mechanic shop and have to fight evil robots

Tags: story-identification, tv

I never actually watched the tv show but remember the commercial for it.

The teens/college students work/hang out at a mechanic shop and somehow gain the ability to become robotic crime fighters (similar to Saban’s *Power Rangers*). The antagonists are CGI robots which look similar to *Transformers Beast Wars*.

I don’t believe it's an adaptation of any tokusatsu series. It may have been on Fox Kids or some other saturday morning programming block.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What country was this?  Was it in English?  Do you have any idea what channel it might have been on?

Answer (score 2):

This could be [*Megas XLR*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megas_XLR), which aired in the Toonami block of Cartoon Network from 2004–2005. It fits your general timeframe, but was a late-night show. From Wikipedia, the main characters are teenage mechanics; they find a giant mecha from the future and repair it. It's an homage/parody of mecha anime without being a direct adaptation.

It looks like the villains are aliens rather than just giant robots, but they might wear robot suits sometimes and have a sort of animalistic aesthetic.